# Google Analytics exclude exact part of url

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I've been searching the web, but can't find a solution. Who can help me?

Situation:
I have a website selling tours with on some pages embedded calendars which all show up as separate pages in Behaviour Report (All Pages).
URI `/embeds/calendar/blablabla`

I also have book buttons which load embedded pages which I do want to track. Those URI's start with `/embeds/book/` and in many of those URI's there's also the word calendar.

So I would like to filter out the pages that match exactly `/embeds/calendar/` but I can't figure out how to do that preferably applying it as a filter to the view or otherwise as a segment.*

In the report itself, I figured out an advanced filter that works:
Exclude > Page > Matching RegExp > `/embeds/calendar/`

*Edit: applying it as a filter to the view or to add this as a segment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question considering that it contains part of the answer. If you want those pages change the filter from `exclude` to `include`.

You can create a segment with user or session level who visited those page path, not those pages alone. For this you have the filter as you have already used.

If you do not want this data to be collected in the view you must enter a filter in the view settings, i.e. Prdefinited `Exclude --> traffic to the subdirectories --> Select expression --> ...` or `Custom Exclude --> Request URI --> ...`. This change will only apply to today's and future data.

Comment: I made it more clear now: how to apply that as a filter to the view or as a segment. And the goal is to exclude those embedded calendars.

Comment: Improved my answer.

Comment: Is there a possibility to prevent the embedded calendar pages from showing up in my data at all?

Comment: Improved my answer.